# MemoryError: Python uses pickle to load GB level file

Tags: python, python-3.x, out-of-memory, pickle

When I use pickle to load a GB file, it report a Memory Error, how can I solve it?

My code is like this:

```
model_file_path = os.path.join(model_directory, model_file_name)
    with open(model_file_path, 'rb') as fh:
        return pickle.load(fh)
```

My python bit is 64, version is 3.4.4.

Comment: How large is the file and how much spare memory do you have? The likelihood is you need more memory, or need to output multiple, smaller pickle files to process in chunks.

Comment: Install more RAM chips?

Comment: Fix your indentation. The `with` statement should not be indented the way it is.

Comment: @MadPhysicist machine RAM is 6GB

Comment: @jpp the file is 1.3GB, and machine RAM is 6GB

Comment: If the problem happens in constant scale, you may try `marshal` in place of `pickle` as it saves memory by skipping cycle detection. No guarantee.

Comment: @Qingqing_L, Yes, but how much **free memory** do you have? the chances are a chunk will be used by other processes.

Comment: @jpp. Not to mention that a 1GB pickle file expands to quite a bit more than 1GB in memory